# 2012 Macbook Pro Black Screen, Fan Spins Up Fast and can't be powered off

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, hardware-recommendation

I was recently asked to fix a 2012 Macbook Pro 13" (MD101LL/A*) and was told it had a drink spilled around or on it.

So it has a green light on the charger and will power on. But the symptoms are that the screen will stay black and not show anything, the fan will spin up slowly to a lot higher than it should, and it can't be powered off by holding the Power Button.

I did already take the logic board out and inspected it and it looks like there's some corrosion damage in a few spots. The components i noted that had corrosion on them i checked the schematics and started checking for voltage coming out of them from the schematics. Most pieces i checked seemed ok, like they were outputting voltage on the pins they should be.

However, i'm just kind of stumbling in the dark trying to figure this out. I'm not exactly sure what specific circuits/systems i need to be checking and how to find out the right voltages/outputs from them. Does anybody have any pointers?